# function hideTable() does not hide all rows

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to hide or show a specific table row,
but the result is to hide only one cell

What am i doing wrong here?

This is the script to call the functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
 window.onload = function() {
var hideTable = localStorage.getItem('hideTable');
if(hideTable === 'true'){
   document.getElementById('tr1').innerHTML = "";

    }
}     

   function showTable() {
   document.getElementById('tr1').style.visibility = "visible";
   localStorage.removeItem('hideTable');  //remove key   
   }
   function hideTable() {
   document.getElementById('tr1').innerHTML = "";
   localStorage.setItem('hideTable' , true);  //remove key   
   }
   if (localStorage.getItem('hideTable')) {  

   hideTable();   //if set show table
   }

</script>
```

Here are the buttons,

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input     type='button' onClick='javascript:showTable();' value='show'></td>
<td><input type='button' onClick='javascript:hideTable();' value='hide'></td>
</tr>
```

and this is the table i want to hide or show

```
<tr id='tr1'>

<?php for($i=5;$i<(count($csv)-1);$i++) { ?>

<td align="center" <?php colorizeTrades($csv3[$i][0], true); ?>><?php echo $csv3[$i][0]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorizeTrades($csv3[$i][1], true); ?>><?php echo $csv3[$i][1]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorizeTrades($csv3[$i][2], true); ?>><?php echo $csv3[$i][2]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorizeTrades($csv3[$i][3], true); ?>><?php echo $csv3[$i][3]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorizeTrades($csv3[$i][4], true); ?>><?php echo $csv3[$i][4]; ?></td>
<td BGCOLOR="white"  align="center"><?php echo $csv3[$i][5]; ?></td>
<td BGCOLOR="white"  align="center"><?php echo $csv3[$i][6]; ?></td>
<td BGCOLOR="AntiqueWhite"  align="center"><?php echo $csv3[$i][7]; ?></td>
<td BGCOLOR="AntiqueWhite"  align="center"><?php echo $csv3[$i][8]; ?></td>

</tr>

<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Renders invalid HTML, <tr> is outside for loop but </tr> is inside. Also, why removing all <td>s? This will break HTML again. Instead make them hidden or invisible.

Comment: You first need to fix your HTML dom, voting to close as syntax error

Comment: If i put the </tr> after the <?php } ?> , the table does not show as it should . This way it works

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. As a side effect, doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely that you will get people to up-vote your posts and makes it more likely that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't matter which style your choose (although, IMO, some are more appropriate for JavaScript than others). But, pick one and use it consistently for all code in a single project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this might be what you are looking for
When you want to hide the row. You need to first select the row then store it in local storage after that remove it from the table.

When you want to show it again. You need to get the row from local storage and then add it to the table

```js
function showRow(){
  var row = localStorage.getItem("hiddenRow");
  $("#myTable").prepend(row);
}
function hideRow(){
  var row =$("#tr1");
  localStorage.setItem("hiddenRow", row);
  $(row).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="showRow()">show</button>
<button onclick="hideRow()">hide</button>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hi 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried it but it still hides only one cell... i think it has something to do with the php loop

Comment: copy and past the html out put of the loop before hiding please @GiannisChristopoulos